# SOAP 1.1 "Client Fault" Error

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, gsoap

I get the following error when I run a web service client that contacts a remote web service server:

```
SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client[no subcode]
"Client fault"
Detail: [no detail]
```

I have looked at the client and the server and I can find no faults. Other web server clients can contact web services on the server no problem. The code to the web service client is [here](http://pastebin.com/BT9iai9e), but more than that, I'm actually just wondering how to go about debugging a problem like this one. The web service client and server were constructed using the gSOAP toolkit.

Also, could it have something to do with web service name spaces? I use the ns namespace for all of my webservice applications. See [this](http://pastebin.com/rrhYwuqa).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that there was an EOF or interruption before the response message was fully delivered to the client. Without further details there is no way of knowing for sure.

I suggest to compile the client with -DDEBUG (macro DEBUG set) to generate log files. The log files will be helpful to determine the cause of the problem.

Use the latest version of gSOAP if possible.